# When is static_assert evaluated relative to template instantiation

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a template function to operate over a recursive data structure.  In the initial function called, I have something of the form:

```
template <unsigned Pos, typename... Ps>
auto get(param<Ps...> i) -> int
{
    static_assert(Pos < sizeof...(Ps), "Error message");
    return helper<Pos>(i.rest);
}
```

In the particular case that I am playing with, I know that `helper<Pos>(i.rest)` will fail to compile because it attempts to go beyond the end of the data structure.

I expected the static_assert to stop compilation, but it appears to instantiate the templates and fail before checking the static_assert.  What is the actual correct behavior?

I am using GCC 4.7.3.

Comment: `Ps` is not a parameter pack, in fact this isn't even close to a compilable example, half the stuff doesn't exist. `param` is nothing there is no `helper` function

Comment: What are you actually trying to solve? This looks like it could be done more simply.

Comment: I am writing something similar to std::get.  I basically have a very special purpose tuple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There ain't no such thing as the order of evaluation of `static_assert`s relative to template instantiations. The standard simply says that, if the expression in the first parameter of `static_assert` evaluates to false at compile time, the program is ill-formed and the diagnostic should include the text from the second parameter.

In other words, `static_assert(false)` is treated the same as a syntax error or any other violation of well-formedness constraints. Naturally, if there are multiple errors that render a program ill-formed, the standard doesn't specify the order in which the compiler should issue diagnostic for them, nor even whether it should issue a message for each error.

Answer (score 0):

To the answer of @Igor I can add that GCC compiler's first pass is as if you only have function declarations, not definitions. So it might instantiate some code without looking into the function body. If something fails at this level, it might not go deeper inside.